# Mutiple insertions of the same data on sqllite database

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, crud

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD form on android development studio.

I can enter data to the database but it seems to only pick up the 'county'  texField. So each record is set to whatever was in the county textField.  I think it might be to do with the item variables and declaration but i cant see whats wrong.
Thank you in advance.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainDatabase";

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private Button btnAdd, btnViewData;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextLast);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editPasswordConfirm);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editPhoneNumber);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editEmailAddress);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editAddressLine1);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editAddressLine2);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.postcodeUser);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.county);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnViewData = findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
                String newName = editText.getText().toString();
                Integer newPass = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                String newPhone = editText.getText().toString();
                String newEmail = editText.getText().toString();
                String newAdd1 = editText.getText().toString();
                String newAdd2 = editText.getText().toString();
                String newPC = editText.getText().toString();
                String newCounty = editText.getText().toString();

                if (editText.length() != 0) {
                    AddData(newEntry, newName, newPass, newPhone, newEmail, newAdd1, newAdd2, newPC, newCounty);


                    editText.setText("");
                } else {
                    toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
                }

            }
        });

        btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainDatabase.this, ListDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }



    public void AddData(String newEntry, String newName, Integer newPass, String newPhone, String newEmail, String newAdd1, String newAdd2, String newPC, String newCounty) {
        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry,newName,newPass,newPhone,newEmail,newAdd1,newAdd2,newPC,newCounty);


        if (insertData) {
            toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
        } else {
            toastMessage("Something went wrong");
        }
    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Database Helper**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by User on 2/28/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "name";
    private static final String COL3 = "lastname";
    private static final String COL4 = "phonenumber";
    private static final String COL5 = "addressline1";
    private static final String COL6 = "addressline2";
    private static final String COL7 = "postcode";
    private static final String COL8 = "county";
    private static final String COL9 = "email";
    private static final String COL10 = "password";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL1 +  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                COL2 +" TEXT," +
                COL3 +" TEXT," +
                COL4 +" INTEGER," +
                COL5 +" TEXT," +
                COL6 +" TEXT,"+
                COL7 +" TEXT,"+
                COL8 +" TEXT,"+
                COL9 +" TEXT,"+
                COL10 +" TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(createTable);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item, String item2, Integer item3, String item4, String item5, String item6, String item7, String item8, String item9) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        contentValues.put(COL3, item2);
        contentValues.put(COL4, item3);
        contentValues.put(COL5, item4);
        contentValues.put(COL6, item5);
        contentValues.put(COL7, item6);
        contentValues.put(COL8, item7);
        contentValues.put(COL9, item8);
        contentValues.put(COL10, item9);


        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + item2 + item3 + item4 + item5 + item6 + item7 + item8 + item9 + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the data from database
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the name field
     * @param newName
     * @param id
     * @param oldName
     */
    public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    /**
     * Delete from database
     * @param id
     * @param name
     */
    public void deleteName(int id, String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.unn.android.loginregister.MainDatabase">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <EditTextFirst
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Firstname" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextLast"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="LastName" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="Password"  />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/editPasswordConfirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="Confirm Password"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/editPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="Phone"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
            android:id="@+id/editEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="Email"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/editAddressLine1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Address Line 1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
            android:id="@+id/editAddressLine2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Address Line 2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:id="@+id/postcodeUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:text="Postcode" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
            android:id="@+id/county"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="County" />


    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

    <!--<RelativeLayout-->

        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="100dp">-->

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="650dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:text="View Data" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Check the editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextLast); you have assigned all the editext to only one variable. That's why you are getting country value only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are only using one variable, namely **editText** for all of the EditText's. So the only EditText that is effectively being used is the **country** (as that is the last EditText assigned to the **editText** variable.)

To fix this you need to :-

1. Declare variables for each of the EditTexts, and
2. Set the variables according to their specific EditText, and
3. Retrieve the value from the respective EditText variables.

e.g. you could have :-

```
public class MainDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainDatabase";

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private Button btnAdd, btnViewData;
    private EditText 
        editText,            
        editTextLast,        //<<<< ADDED
        editPassword,        //<<<< ADDED
        editPasswordConfirm, //<<<< ADDED
        editPhoneNumber,     //<<<< ADDED
        editEmailAddress,    //<<<< ADDED
        editAddressLine1,    //<<<< ADDED
        editAddressLine2,    //<<<< ADDED
        postcodeUser,        //<<<< ADDED
        country;             //<<<< ADDED

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editTextLast = findViewById(R.id.editTextLast); //<<<< CHANGED
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editPassword); //<<<< CHANGED
        editPasswordConfirm = findViewById(R.id.editPasswordConfirm); //<<<< CHANGED
        editPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.editPhoneNumber); //<<<< CHANGED
        editEmailAddress = findViewById(R.id.editEmailAddress); //<<<< CHANGED
        editAddressLine1 = findViewById(R.id.editAddressLine1); //<<<<CHANGED
        editAddressLine2 = findViewById(R.id.editAddressLine2); //<<<< CHANGEDX
        postcodeUser = findViewById(R.id.postcodeUser); //<<<< CHANGED
        country = findViewById(R.id.county); //<<<< CHANGED
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnViewData = findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
                String newName = editTextLast.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED
                Integer newPass = Integer.parseInt(editPassword.getText().toString()); //<<<< CHANGED
                String newPhone = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED
                String newEmail = editEmailAddress.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED
                String newAdd1 = editAddressLine1.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED
                String newAdd2 = editAddressLine2.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED
                String newPC = postcodeUser.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED
                String newCounty = country.getText().toString(); //<<<< CHANGED

                if (editText.length() != 0) {
                    AddData(newEntry, newName, newPass, newPhone, newEmail, newAdd1, newAdd2, newPC, newCounty);


                    editText.setText("");
                } else {
                    toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
                }

            }
        });

        btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainDatabase.this, ListDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }



    public void AddData(String newEntry, String newName, Integer newPass, String newPhone, String newEmail, String newAdd1, String newAdd2, String newPC, String newCounty) {
        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry,newName,newPass,newPhone,newEmail,newAdd1,newAdd2,newPC,newCounty);


        if (insertData) {
            toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
        } else {
            toastMessage("Something went wrong");
        }
    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Note** the above is in-principle code and has not been tested. As such it may contain some errors.

Comment: @TimmyOgden that's good could you please tick the question as answered.